# Firestore real time data update by limit on the last added documents

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a firestore database where it gets new documents every second from another gcp service, I'm using that data to plot a line chart in front end angular12 app. the problem I have is the front end is getting the whole database documents which it fills the chart with over 1000 data, I tried to use ref.limit but then I don't get the latest document and the chart keeps showing the same 10 objects. has anyone faced the same problem and what would be the best approach?

in service.ts

```
export class ChartsService {
  
    private itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item>;
    items: Observable<Item[]>;  

    constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
      this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<Item>('DCI2');
      this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
    }
```

componant.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.ChartsService.getDocs().subscribe((data) => {
          this.items$ = data;
         
          if (this.items$) {
            this.items$.forEach((element) => {
              this.timestamp.push(element.timestamp);
              this.temp1.push(element.temp1); 
              this.temp2.push(element.temp2)      
            });

            console.log(this.temp1);
 
          }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have a timestamp in your documents, you can order by descending date and then limit:

```
this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<Item>('DCI2', ref => ref.orderBy("timestamp", desc).limit(10));
this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
```

Also see the AngularFire documentation on [querying collections](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md).

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your suggestion, and yes I'm using firestore database and using ('DCI2', ref => ref.orderBy("timestamp", desc).limit(10)) in collection it only reserves that 10 values and does not updates after when new values/elements get added to the firestore database. how can I keep reading the last 10 pushed constantly? TIA

Comment: If new items have a newer `timestamp` value, they should show up in the `valueChanges` stream. If that's not happening for you, can you set up a [repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on a site like jsbin or stackblitz?

Comment: with the type of gcp account being private I won't be able to run it on stackblitz, I feel my problem is with the array maybe to keep it updating. using 'limit' and 'orderBy' before valueChanges is preventing the new docs update/stream.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2207024 
I created a snip of the code if thats help

Comment: Not really, as I can't easily run that code